# Did Stonewall Jackson suggest to fight naked?

Tags: american-civil-war

Fremantle, [*Three Months in the Southern States*](https://archive.org/details/threemonthsinso00colgoog), pp. 132-3:

> General [James E.] Slaughter declared that on the night after the
> terrific repulse of Burnside’s army at Fredericksburg, Stonewall
> Jackson had made the following suggestion :— “I am of opinion that we
> ought to attack the enemy at once; and in order to avoid the
> confusion and mistakes so common in a night-attack, I recommend that
> we should all strip ourselves perfectly naked.”

Is this true? [Apparently](https://www.historynet.com/naked-knife-wielding-rebels-fredericksburg.htm), some think the story was invented after the war, but Fremantle's book was published in 1863.

Comment: Please don't tell me how he planned for the men to carry their ammunition...

Comment: Footnote at the bottom of the [original authors page](https://archive.org/details/threemonthsinso00colgoog/page/n149/mode/2up) indicates Fremantle doubted the story as well: *I always forgot to ask General Lee whether this story was a true one.*

Comment: @T.E.D. in the normal webbing (or whatever it was), I assume. Likewise, I don't think he intended for them to be bare-footed.

Comment: @justCal I don't think it necessarily means he doubted it. He just regretted not asking Lee when he had the chance.